# Как реализовать потоки в Visual C++?

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

Подскажите как создавать и управлять потоками в Visual C++ ? Есть ли какая-нибудь информация новее http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815805/ru ? Мне нужно что-то вроде в одной кнопке создание потока и его старт, в другой пауза потока, в третьей стоп. Моя попытка:

```
Thread^ thread = gcnew Thread( gcnew ThreadStart( ThreadProc() ));
thread->Start();
```

в кнопке старта потока. И соответственно функция

```
void ThreadProc() {
listBox1->BeginUpdate();

listBox1->Items->Add( String::Format( "Поток работает") );

listBox1->EndUpdate();

}
```

Закончилось место в комментариях, поэтому пишу сюда: [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), я начал писать программу на C++ т.к. плохо знаю C#, но наверное придется переделывать программу под C#. Неужели нет ни одного способа сделать поток под мои нужды?

Comment: Это C++ или C++/CLI? Вам нужен нативный или управляемый поток? (Если вы не знаете, что означают эти слова, то нативный.)

Попробуйте воспользоваться `std::thread`.

Если вы по незнанию пишете оконное приложение на C++CLI, немедленно бросьте каку. Либо C#/WPF, либо C#/WinForms, либо C++/MFC, либо C++/Qt.

Comment: Да в том то и дело, что сами Windows Form и С++ я знаю средне, но с потоками столкнулся впервые. И пока нигде внятного описания что и как делать я не нашел. Мне нужен поток только для 1 функции: запуск/пауза методов в моей программе и все.

Comment: @MartinSeptim вы действительно не видите разницы между С++ и С++/CLI?

Comment: @MartinSeptim: расскажите о том, что за приложение вы пишете. Почему вы выбрали C++/CLI? (В нормальном C++ нету ни `^`, ни `gcnew`.)

Comment: @MartinSeptim приведенный вами код, как уже справедливо заметил @VladD, - это именно С++/CLI, язык, у которого с обычным С++ не так много общего. Если вы пишете именно на нем, то я могу лишь предположить, что работа с потоками там может строиться вокруг взаимодействия с классом Thread из .NET

Comment: @VladD, @DreamChild Я пишу простую программу для обработки данных (долго объяснять в чем смысл), и по заданию мне осталось реализовать 2 вещи: запуск/пауза процесса обработки и progresBar этого же процесса.

Comment: Мне не слишком важно как будет реализован запуск и пауза процесса обработки, нужно лишь что бы по нажатию на одну кнопку формы этот процесс запускался, а по нажатию на другую - становился на паузу.

Comment: А почему тогда не командная строка? Там, правда, придётся повозится с паузой. В любом случае, многопоточные программы довольно сложны в написании и требуют определённых умений.

А как вы планируете сообщать бегущему процессу обработки, что ему надо приостановиться?

Comment: По заданию нужен графический интерфейс для программы. Я представлял себе это как в С# т.е. Tread.Start() и прочее

Comment: @MartinSeptim: а почему тогда вся программа не на C#?

Если ваши расчёты уже сделаны на C++, можно написать UI отдельно на C# и подключить в один проект. Нет, серьёзно.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть вот этот [пример ][1]. Здесь вам и C++/MFC, и старт/пауза/запуск потока, и графический интерфейс, который нужно всего-то переделать под свои нужды :)


  [1]: http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_MFC_Samples/WaitForSingleObject-_beginthreadex-SetEvent-Start-Stop-Thread-VC-MFC-Example.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Есть [std::thread](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) для нативного кода. Это предпочтительный, кросс-платформенный вариант.
- Для CLR класс [System:Threading::Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1). Для него требуется .NET.

Пробуйте, что вам удобнее под конкретную задачу.

BeginUpdate нет смысла использовать для одного обновления. Само обновление нельзя сделать в WindowsForms из другого потока. Для этого нужно использовать метод [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) или [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx), чтобы уж совсем многопоточно.